# Анимация массива с использованием matplotlib в python

Tags: python, анимация, matplotlib, физика

Здравствуйте, у меня следующая проблема. Я решил уравнение теплопроводности и получил массив эволюции температурного профиля в координатах - пространство температура .Очень нужно сделать анимацию, чтобы посмотреть поведение по времени на всем отрезке (а не в конкретной точке)
Есть ли такая функция чтобы просто загрузить два массива , как в plt.plot(x,y) но массив y вводить в цикле?

Comment: вы можете выложить пример своих данных?

Comment: Начните с [примеров анимации](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/). Посмотрите какой из них ближе к вашему случаю¶ Создайте минимальный пример кода с искусственными данными, который ваш пример показывает.